# Simple PHP REST server with secure user authentication and registered third party applications

Tags: php, rest, restful-authentication

I'm looking into writing an PHP REST API that would allow registered users interact with the web service from third party applications.

What I need the API to be able to do is:

- provide support for secure user authentication
- allow registered users to interact with the service from 3rd party applications
- this applications should be registered and approved on the system beforehand (similar to twitter)

I was wondering what would be a good framework or library to start from that provides a good basis for such a service.

titel

Comment: Related: [Web service construction toolkit / wrapper for PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967991/web-service-construction-toolkit-wrapper-for-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an OAuthProvider would do what you describe.
Here are some tutorials on how to make an OAuthProvider using PHP's OAuth module.

http://toys.lerdorf.com/archives/55-Writing-an-OAuth-Provider-Service.html

http://djpate.com/2011/01/13/how-to-write-a-complete-oauth-provider-in-php5/

Answer (score 0):

You could try one of the OAuth libraries for PHP listed on http://oauth.net/code