# Windows 8 App C# string to PHP crypted

Tags: c#, php, encryption, windows-8

I want to send data from my C# Windows 8 App to a PHP Script on my webserver to save Highscores etc.
But to avoid Manual insertions of fictional highscore values, I think I have to en- and decrypt it.
In which way can I encrypt data in C# which I can decrypt in PHP and maybe in the other way?

Or are there other Solutions to realize it?

Comment: How do you want to encrypt the data? There are a lot of algorithms to choose from.

Comment: I have no experience with data Encryption ... I'm looking for a simple algorithm which I can use in both languages, espacially in php ... I have not full Access to the Server to install Special Extensions or something else.

Comment: Start with MD5 (even though it's old and not secure anymore). You need to do some research yourself if you need something better.

Comment: As far as I know, is MD5 a One-Way-Decryption, which cannot be (easily) encrypted

Comment: It is a hashing method (encryption in one direction). Use it only for passwords, which you should never decrypt.

Comment: But I want to submit decrypted Data (as a string) from my Windows 8.1 App C# to PHP where I can encrypt the data to store the values in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to encrypt/decrypt data web-transmitted data is using the HTTPS protocol. All encryption/decryption happens automatically once the client and server authenticate and trust each other after exchanging certificates.

To avoid fake data talk only to authenticated clients that are authorized to insert the scores.

So you'd have a list of trusted clients, talk to them over HTTPS and each session would start by authentication (client would prove its identity to your server).

In my opinion the key terms you should definitely take into consideration are `HTTPS (SSL Certificate)`, `REST`, `OAuth`

You may want to start by reading the

> [Open Web Application Security Project (OWASP) - Authentication Cheat Sheet](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet)

After that you may find useful some followup technical questions like:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/3605/certificate-based-authentication-vs-username-and-password-authentication
- [How to build a secure and RESTful service in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5816233/how-to-build-a-secure-and-restful-service-in-php)
- [Simple PHP REST server with secure user authentication and registered third party applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4122962/simple-php-rest-server-with-secure-user-authentication-and-registered-third-part)
- ...?